# Why do I get this error saying I have a typo in sql?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I keep getting this error, where it says there is a typo in my code and `SERT` is mispelled instead of `INSERT`. However, my code has no typos at all and definitely does not uses SERT instead of INSERT. I am using MariaDB.

This is the error:
2 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "SERT" at position 0)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "INTO" at position 5)

This is the code I used:

```
INSERT INTO foods (Food, Location, Image, Calories, Fats, Carbs, Sugar, Protein, Salt) 
VALUES
(
'! Hähnchen-Jackfruit Frikadellen mit Petersilie', 'Germany', 'https://images.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/400/478/607/8501/front_en.13.40.jpg', 160, 10, 2.5, 0.3, 13, 1.8
),
(
'#1 Pita Bread 14 Jack Junior', 'United States', 'https://images.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/007/659/230/0033/front_en.4.40.jpg', 206.89, 0, 44.82, 0, 6.89, 0.43
);
COMMIT;
```

The only other code was when I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foods(
`Food` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`Location` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`Image` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`Calories` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
`Fats` decimal(22,1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Carbs` decimal(22,1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Sugar` decimal(22,1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Protein` decimal(22,1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Salt` decimal(22,1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Has anyone else had this problem before or know how to fix it?

Please ask if you need any more information

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you are using to run this statement

Comment: Did you execute the code directly using a tool like Workbench or is it part of a larger code in application?

Comment: @ysth I have added the extra code

Comment: @FanoFN I did it in my browser with phpmyadmin

Comment: Is it exactly like this? https://imgur.com/YjoCkkB

Comment: @FanoFN, yes it is that

Comment: Did you maybe select that statement before you hit "execute", and missed the initial "IN"?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I did it by uploading the file with the code in it so nothing like that could have happened

Comment: Check the file for non printable characters?

Comment: @TheCoder The image shows a red line underneath command "commit;". I tested the insert statement without `commit`. No errors. When you want to use "commit;" it needs an active transaction.

Comment: Hmm, can you try `CREATE TABLE foods(
Food varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL, ...)` and then run the insert statement. Will the same error orcure again?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image at imgur, you are using `COMMIT` but there isn't transaction initiated, in fact, MyISAM engine doesn't use transactions. So, just don't use that line.

Like this

```sql
INSERT INTO foods (Food, Location, Image, Calories, Fats, Carbs, Sugar, Protein, Salt) 
VALUES
(
'! Hähnchen-Jackfruit Frikadellen mit Petersilie', 'Germany', 'https://images.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/400/478/607/8501/front_en.13.40.jpg', 160, 10, 2.5, 0.3, 13, 1.8
),
(
'#1 Pita Bread 14 Jack Junior', 'United States', 'https://images.openfoodfacts.org/images/products/007/659/230/0033/front_en.4.40.jpg', 206.89, 0, 44.82, 0, 6.89, 0.43
);
```

If you want to use transactions, you must change the table engine to `InnoDB`. As mentioned [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/transactions/)